# Pagination for REST API (Query request) Datatables

Tags: javascript, api, rest, pagination, datatables

I have a REST Api command that get an MYSQL query inside and perform it so now with this I request a select and put it on table and the table will convert to Datatables. The problem start becuase I don't want to get the whole data in once so I should perform the MYSQL query with limit for example 10 record each time, and I need a pagination that work for it and another thing that I need is a search function which search from db instead of dom.

```
function getnames() {
    var Group = $("#traderGroup").val();
    var Sql = "select NAME,LOGIN,EMAIL from users";
    getNames = {"Sql":Sql};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://test.com/api/db/select",
        data: JSON.stringify(getNames),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: true,
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Data.length; i++) {
                $("<tr><td align='center'>" + data.Data[i].LOGIN + "</td><td>" + data.Data[i].NAME + "</td><td>" + data.Data[i].EMAIL + "</td></tr>").appendTo("#ajaxResponse3").hide().fadeIn(500);
            }
        },
        error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: apiurl+'Token',
                    data: loginData
                }).done(function(data) {                                        
            });
            $("<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>Something Went Wrong!! Please contact the IT Department.</div>").prependTo("#alert").hide().fadeIn(500);
        },
        beforeSend : function(xhr){
            $('#processing-modal').modal('show');
        },
        complete : function(){
            $('#processing-modal').modal('hide');
            table = $('#tablename').dataTable({
                responsive: true,
                "search": {"smart": true,"regex": true}
            });
            var tableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(table, {
                "sButtons": ["copy","csv","xls","pdf",{ "type": "print", "buttonText": "Print me!" } ],
                "sSwfPath": "https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" 
            });
            $(tableTools.fnContainer()).insertAfter('div.tabletools h3');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Watch the possibility of SQL injection with your query too!

Comment: No worry bro SQL injection in my case not a problem first cause my Queries is filtered by web api only Select is acceptable and also is in the internal backend that only two person have access two and the system is IP filtered and have permissions too ;)

Answer (score 0):

seems as though you're using ajax to populate a table and then calling the datatable rather than getting the table to get its own data via [ajax](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)?

Datatables allow you to use [serverside](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide) and [processing](https://datatables.net/reference/option/processing) to get all the stuff you, and your table, need... I recently wrote [my own serverSide script](http://drmsite.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/datatables-custom-server-side-script.html) and it's surprisingly easy! There's [another example](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) on the site as well and it's a brilliant starting point.

Not really an answer to your question I'm afraid excepting to say that if you want to get there you should perhaps look at setting off from somewhere else...

Dom